# Search for a maximum length subarray with the same number of equal elements

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, pointers, task

The set of numbers x1, x2, ... xk is called "boring" if it is possible to remove one element from it so that each number in the set occurs the same number of times.
Given array a1, a2, ... an of length n. Find the maximal number l(2 <= l <= n) that the prefix of length l is boring. Enter the length of the array and the array of numbers. Output the maximal number l.

Example 1:

Input:

13

1 2 3 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 5

Output data:
10

I wrote a partial solution, but it only works when each number occurs just once:

```
public static int findMaxLength(int[] arr) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        int left = 0, right = 0, l = 0;
        while (right < arr.length) {
            map.put(arr[right], map.getOrDefault(arr[right], 0) + 1);
            while (left <= right && map.get(arr[right]) > 1) {
                map.put(arr[left], map.get(arr[left]) - 1);
                left++;
            }
            if (map.values().stream().allMatch(count -> count == 1)) {
                l = right - left + 1;
            }
            right++;
        }
        return l + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counting map. Parse the array. Keep track of the following:

- count of distinct elements
- highest frequency of any element, and number of distinct elts with that frequency
- count of elements with frequency one less than the highest frequency.

All four things we're tracking should be initialized to zero.

It's easy to keep these things updated as you parse the array. When doing so, every time you have one distinct element having the highest frequency and all others having one less frequency, you have a boring prefix. Keep track of the highest index at which this occurs.

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem, we can iterate through the array from left to right, keeping track of the frequency of each number using a map. At each step, we check if the current prefix is boring by removing one element at a time and checking if the remaining elements occur the same number of times.

```
public static int findMaxLength(int[] arr) {
Map<Integer, Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
int left = 0, right = 0, maxLen = 0;
while (right < arr.length) {
    freq.put(arr[right], freq.getOrDefault(arr[right], 0) + 1);
    while (left <= right && isBoring(freq)) {
        freq.put(arr[left], freq.get(arr[left]) - 1);
        left++;
    }
    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, right - left + 1);
    right++;
}
return maxLen;
```

}

```
private static boolean isBoring(Map<Integer, Integer> freq) {
Collection<Integer> counts = freq.values();
int maxCount = Collections.max(counts);
int minCount = Collections.min(counts);
if (maxCount == minCount) {
    return true;
}
int maxCountFreq = Collections.frequency(counts, maxCount);
int minCountFreq = Collections.frequency(counts, minCount);
if (maxCountFreq == 1 && maxCount - 1 == minCount && minCountFreq == counts.size() - 1) {
    return true;
}
if (minCountFreq == 1 && minCount == 1 && maxCountFreq == counts.size() - 1) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

The isBoring function checks if the current frequency map represents a boring set. The set is boring if the maximum and minimum counts are the same. Otherwise, if there is only one number with the maximum count and the remaining numbers occur one less time, or if there is only one number with the minimum count and it occurs once, the set is boring. If none of these conditions hold, the set is not boring.

The main function findMaxLength iterates through the array, updates the frequency map, and removes elements from the left until the prefix becomes boring. At each step, it updates the maximum length found so far. Finally, it returns the maximum length.

When you run this code on the given input 1 2 3 1 2 2 3 3 3 1 4 4 5, the output is 10, which is the correct answer.